# XPATH - how to combine AND / OR

Tags: xpath

I have the following XPATH expression:

```
/prod[price/buynow[1] > 19 and text/desc[1][not(contains(.,"bier"))] or text/desc[1][not(contains(.,"kalender"))] or text/desc[1][not(contains(.,"ballon"))]]
```

I need the first part ( > 19) to be true for all data, whereas the following conditions can be OR.

Comment: Try this `/prod[price/buynow[1] > 19 and (text/desc[1][not(contains(.,"bier"))]|text/desc[1][not(contains(.,"kalender"))]|text/desc[1][not(contains(.,"ballon"))]])`.

Comment: `must-be-true and (this or that or the-other ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, but the syntax using () to group the ORs does not seem to be right. Any other solution for `must-be-true AND (cond1 OR cond 2 OR cond3)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
expression and (expression or expression)
```

Here is working [example](http://xpather.com/tTRWHFTb)

Comment: @Till have you found a solution?